# TS2339 (TS) Property 'state' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2019

I had my react project working fine using Visual Studio 2019 and typescript. After 1 month without coding I open the Visual Studio solution and I was alerted to update typescript 3.4 to 3.5. And now, suddenly I have a Build error on this.state definition of the component.

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h4LzcpLqSHrsUdCNefMhlbBq7NpCd-u6/view?usp=sharing)

```
export default class Employee extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            user: null,
            loading: true
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the full file, what is AdminDropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using typescript you need to change it to this to declare the state interface:

```
interface IState = {
  user: any;
  loading: boolean;
}
```

Then the class declaration:

```
export default class Employee extends React.Component<any, IState> { }
```

Comment: To ermove the any, you could ust wirte it with {}:  React.Component<{}, IState> { }, which will prevent unknown props in the future.

Comment: Yes, I assumed he would have props.

Comment: But it has been working fine in production since today.

Comment: tsc won't stop it being compiled - it will be transpiled to javascript and this is valid javascript so production code won't be affected. Your IDE has thrown this error because it -is- a typescript error.

Comment: yes thanks! Typescript 3.5 now need this implementation